# Java shared hosting with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, shared-hosting

I've been developing a disaster risk management application that makes use of Java/Smart GWT, PostgreSQL/PostGIS, and Tomcat 7. I'm looking for a shared hosting environment for the beta testing period (about 6 months).

My current hosting provider does not provide PostGIS, or PostgreSQL greater than version 8.1. Any pointers or advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What about Red Hat's [OpenShift](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/)? It's not quite shared hosting but it should fit your needs.

> OpenShift is Red Hat's free, auto-scaling Platform as a Service (PaaS)
>   for applications. As an application platform in the cloud, OpenShift
>   manages the stack so you can focus on your code.

No need to bother with component installation. Just pick the Java cartridge and then after that, add the Postgresql cartridge ( that already includes the PostGIS plugin ). You can check the list of supported features [here](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/developers/technologies).

Oh and did I tell you that you could try it for free? They have a free tier which supports up to three gears.

> A gear is a resource constrained container that runs one or more
>   user-specified software stacks, also known as cartridges. Each gear
>   has a limited amount of RAM and disk space. If an application needs
>   more resources, it can use multiple gears.

[image]

Since your components are basically Java, PostGIS and Tomcat, that should fit right in.

I hope that works for you :)

Comment: This sounds interesting. I'm currently trying out AcuGIS. I'll see how it goes before considering this, though.

Comment: OpenShift provides PostgreSQL 8.4. You can vote for an upgrade here: https://openshift.redhat.com/community/content/ability-to-update-postgresql-to-current-stable

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and decided to create a VM.
I have set up a similar environment on [serversanddomains.com](http://serversanddomains.com/). I recommend creating a VM with the VPS option (12 usd/month, 2Gb Ram VM).

My web app is a more general data exploration app with OSM maps,  but for the momment I on added the data for Portugal to SQL.
http://tinyurl.com/7jc833d

regards
Joaquim.

Comment: I've been checking it out, and I've sent an enquiry. Will I be able to install all the software components I need? JDK, Tomcat, PostgreSQL, PostGIS? Do they provide SSH access?

Answer (score 0):

I think [Alwaysdata](https://www.alwaysdata.com/) could fit your needs for testing purpose, (java, Posgtresql 9.0, Postgis). I don't know if Tomcat server is supported, but you can ask the support team. You could test with a free account(10 mb). It's very small but it's useful.

Comment: Thanks, @geogeek. I'll get in touch with them. Even though from the info on the site, they don't seem to support Java. But I'll request for more info from their sales.